# Experiencing a frozen blank page on Google Script editor from Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-editor

this morning, opening the Script Editor from Google Drive, on chrome browser, I get a frozen page, with the script area blank, and the menu greyed and disabled.
This happen on my scripts, but also on other users.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch you drive locale settings to English and it will work. This is a temporary workaround to use until they fix the bug. [see issue 4339](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4339)

Comment: Done, thanks. I tried also with Chrome language setting, but it requires just the Drive language choice.

Comment: Thanks! just have to go in File > settings and set the language to English